# How long i will run a timer in background?

Tags: audio, ios7, timer

In my application i am running a timer in background for every 8 seconds to play a custom sound,it works fine ,but it get stops at later sometime,so how can i play the sound continuously in background?
Currently i am using the below code to play the sound in background

```
      SystemSoundID soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

let me know the good solution to play the sound continuously in background

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: your app is simply suspended.

**Long answer**: You are missing key parts of the background savvy implementation.

1. You need to tell the iOS that you are an *Audio App*, and that you are requesting extra cycles when suspended.
2. The `UIBackgroundModes` is subject to approval

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20):

**Background modes for apps**:
`UIBackgroundModes` value = `audio`

*The app plays audible content to the user or records audio while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)*

If your app does not fall into any of the categories below, then your only option to extend backgrounding beyond the typical **5** seconds is to invoke `-beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:`. You will likely be suspend within **30** seconds or so.

- audio
- location
- voip
- newsstand-content
- external-accessory
- bluetooth-central & bluetooth-peripheral
- fetch
- remote-notification