# Executing background task upon receiving Remote Notifications(Silent Push) on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, apple-push-notifications, multitasking, backgrounding

I am currently building an app that utilizes iOS 7's Silent Push Notifications to wake the app in background on request.

As I would do in `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` I initiated a background task in `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` which looks like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler

{

    self.taskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.taskId];

        self.taskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;



        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    }];

}
```

While the app successfully registers for remote notifications and `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is called on notification arrival, the app stays in background for just few seconds before returning to suspended state, much shorter than expected execution time given (when called in `-applicationDidEnterBackground:`) which I believe is around 3 minutes.

Is this an expected behaviour? Or is it not possible using remote notifications?

Comment: I believe this may be the same issue as described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889335/how-long-i-will-run-a-timer-in-background/24894486#24894486

Comment: How have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly configured the plist?

1. You need to tell the iOS that you are an *remote-notification App*, and that you are requesting extra cycles when suspended.
2. The `UIBackgroundModes` is subject to approval

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20):

**Background modes for apps**:
`UIBackgroundModes` value = `remote-notification`

*The app wants to start downloading content when a push notification arrives. Use this notification to minimize the delay in showing content related to the push notification.*